# Print row with empty fields in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Say I have a CSV file that has `|` as a delimiter. I know how to read and print the content but I'm not sure how to go about printing `Row 7 has an empty field`. It would be nice to show which field it is but my concern right now is to show me the row first and I can try to do the second task.

```
require 'csv'
require 'pp'

CSV.open("exam.txt", 'r',"|") do |row|
  pp row
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'csv'
require 'pp'

i = 0
CSV.open("exam.txt", 'r',"|") do |row|
  i += 1;
  pp row
  pp "Row " << i.to_s << " has an empty field" if row.include?(nil)
end
```

You can use something like `row.index(nil)` to find the `nil` field. Read the [`Enumerable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) and [`Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html) documentation, you'll probably find something.

Answer (score 1):

Since the CSV library includes Ruby's Enumerable module, you can use [Enumerable's `each_with_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001511) method. Keep in mind that the index is 0-based.

```
CSV.open("exam.txt", "r", "|").each_with_index do |row, index|
  pp row
  # If it's blank:
  pp "Row #{index + 1} has an empty field"
end
```